# SQLAlchemy bulk_update_mappings() not working, but no error messages

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I am trying to update records in a PostgreSQL database using bulk_update_mappings(). Here's a look at one of my mappings:

```
edits_dict[0:1]

[{'utility_id': 1,
  'top_10': 0,
  'top_15': 0,
  'region': 'Midwest',
  'customer_size': 'Largest',
  'nerc_region': 'PJM',
  'pct_purchased_whole': 1.0,
  'can_own_gen': 0.0}]
```

utility_id is my primary key.
I automatically generate the class:

```
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
Utilities = Base.classes.utilities
```

And attempt to test the bulk update with just one mapping:

```
session = Session(engine)
session.bulk_update_mappings(Utilities, edits_dict[0:1])
session.commit()
```

I get no error messages; however, when I query my table after the commit, no changes have been made.

I've run session.dirty before committing and I get an empty list so it seems like the function is just not doing anything.

Comment: `session.dirty` will not show the actions by the bulk update, since it sidesteps most unit of work machinery in favour of performance, as noted in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @IljaEverilä

Answer (score 0):

I queried my table this morning and the changes have been made. It just took a little longer than I had expected.